# extract docker-compose file volumes with regex

Tags: regex, bash, docker-compose

I'm trying to extract all containers' bind-mounts/volumes of a docker-compose file with regex.

The pattern that I've made for such purpose is:

`/volumes:\n(?:^[ \n]+- ?(\S+))/gm`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hToMyu/3)

But it only selects the first volume/bind-mount of each container.

How can I make it to select **ALL** `volumes` list items?

Comment: Why `bash` tag? Please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match volumes: and a newline followed by matching all lines that start with 1 or more spaces and then  `-`

```
\bvolumes:\r?\n((?:[^\S\r\n]+- .*(?:\r?\n|$))*)
```

- `\bvolumes:\r?\n`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `[^\S\r\n]+` Match 1+ whitespaces except for newlines
    - `- .*(?:\r?\n|$)` Match `-`  followed by the rest of the string
  - `)*` Close non capture group and repeat 0+ times
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HNttZu/1)

If volumes must be at the start of the line, you can match it preceded by optional spaces.

```
^[^\S\r\n]*volumes:\r?\n((?:[^\S\r\n]+- .*(?:\r?\n|$))*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Emv7VG/1)

Comment: Thanks it's working. But can we make to capture every volume item as a group?

Comment: @Erfun What is the tool or language? One option is to split the value of group 1 on a newline to get the separate parts. In .NET there is a captures collection, but mostly you have to specify the groups to get them by number.

Comment: I wanted to use this pattern in Bash but it seems that Bash does not support PCRE regex, so I did the job with Python and it's fine. Thanks.